# CEV Model Primer

Tags: calibration, models

Could someone please point out to a good primer on CEV model?
I am trying to get a basic grasp of the model: The dynamics, advantages & disadvantages, for which payoff it is usually used (Hybrid models??), how is it typically calibrated...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this blog post: [link](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/stochastic-calculus/estimate-cev-process/). It has simulation, parameter estimation in python and Proof sketch.

You can also check the John Hull book (ch 27.1) or Brigo and Mercurio (ch 10.2)